# Azure Container Instance does not respond with dns name on browser

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have docker image which locally listens port 5000.
I have deployed images to Azure Container Registry.

I have then created Azure Container Instance with:

```
az container create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name aci-tutorial-app --image <acrLoginServer>/aci-tutorial-app:v1 --cpu 1 --memory 1 --registry-login-server <acrLoginServer> --registry-username <service-principal-ID> --registry-password <service-principal-password> --dns-name-label <aciDnsLabel> --ports 80
```

Container was succesfully created, but browser does not respond with DNS name. Logs look like following.

```
PS C:\azure\ACIPythonAPI> az container logs --resource-group My-Container-RG --name mycontainer
[2022-01-10 08:33:36 +0000] [18] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-01-10 08:33:36 +0000] [18] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (18)
[2022-01-10 08:33:37 +0000] [18] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-01-10 08:33:37 +0000] [25] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25
```

What could be problem? Port definitions are incorrect in docker? How to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you please let me know name of docker image you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested in my environment, and it is working fine for me. I am using ***`nginx`*** images and pushed to container registry.

[image]

[image]

Created container instance using image from container registry which recently pushed.I am using the same command which you have used to create container.

[image]

Would suggest you use ***`FDQN`*** or ***`Public IPAddress`*** of container instance to hit on browser and able to see response from container instance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar my issue,  I update expose port in image file to similar with azure instance port. it work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).