# Azure container instance is not accessible using URL via browser

Tags: docker, azure-cognitive-services, azure-container-instances

I have created a new Container instance in Azure. Below are the steps.

Step:1- I created a new Cognitive Services (A Language Service) and used its "Key" and "Endpoint" value inside Container Instance

Step:2- I created a new Container Instance, and provide it all the required information as mentioned in the below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal

but I changed the PORT 80 to "5001" and Image "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/textanalytics/healthcare:latest".

Below are env variable I used

```
                    {
                        "name": "Eula",
                        "value": "accept"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "RAI_TERMS",
                        "value": "accept"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Billing",
                        "value": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ApiKey",
                        "value": "4a46537f51f64765864cabc20318bdcc"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "enablelro",
                        "value": "true"
                    }
```

Finally it was created and deployed successfully. Now I tried to access it via below url
http://FQDN:5001/Demo/

FQDN--> qualified domain name is used in the url

its not accessible though instance is up and running properly.

Comment: "ipAddress": {
            "ports": [
                {
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "port": 5001
                }
            ],
            "ip": "xx.yyy.zz.238",
            "type": "Public",
            "dnsNameLabel": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
            "autoGeneratedDomainNameLabelScope": "Unsecure",
            "fqdn": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.westus.azurecontainer.io"
        },

Comment: Use only FDQN name on browswer and then try to access. don't try like this http://FQDN:5001/Demo/.

Comment: or Use IP address of Contaner Instance.

Comment: Neither IP nor FDQN name is working for me .

Comment: Can you please show how you are doing the steps 1.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter from which port you are trying to access. instead of using this url `http://FQDN:5001/Demo/` would suggest you please use FDQN or IP address of container instance.

Using the complete FQDN when identifying something is the way it is supposed to be.

You can refer this [***thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683729/azure-container-instance-does-not-respond-with-dns-name-on-browser/70830233#70830233) same i have reprod related to your question. In which i have used FDQN to access the Conatainer Instance.

Comment: Not working. It is not accessible via url at all.